# CSS the last of the same p tags in a row?

Tags: html, css, selector

```
<div class="content" v-html="data">
  <h2>TEST</h2>
  <p>Test<p/>
  <p>Test<p/>
  <p>Test<p/> ------ this
  <h2>TEST</h2>
  <p>Test<p/> ------ this
  <h3>TEST</h3>
  <h4>TEST</h4>
  <p>Test<p/>
  <p>Test<p/> ------ this
  <h2>TEST</h2>
</div>
```

---

```
p+p:last-child {
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

---

I did this but it doesn't work.

I showed in code what I want to access

NOTE: Data is coming dynamically i am printing it with innerHtml

Comment: `p:last-of-type` will grab the bottom one, but there's no way to use first/last/nth to reference these purely in CSS. You either need divs around the sections, or you'd need to use javascript to walk the DOM.

Comment: There's no way of getting what you want in CSS. Sounds like you should alter your HTML structure. For instance, wrapping each part in `<section>`...`</section>`.

Comment: There is no pure CSS solution for this without changing the HTML code or using javascript. You either need to apply classes to the desired `p` tags or wrap the `h2` and subsequent `p` tags in wrapper divs (then you could use `last-child`)

Comment: what you want to do after the selection, we can probably solve the initial problem without such selector